# Random Media Pauses

Tags: logging

I have a strange problem that started recently where media I'm listening to/watching will randomly pause. It happens both when playing on my phone and when playing over bluetooth to my car or headphones. Sometimes it happens when my phone is sitting on the counter and I'm not touching it. I've had it happen in both Pocket Casts and Youtube Vanced, but those are the only two media apps I use regularly. Sometimes it happens shortly after media starts, sometimes it's after I've been watching/listening for a long time.

I was able to grab a logcat where I started a podcast and then it paused a second or two after it started. I've tried to read through it but I can't really make sense of it. Here are two sections I think might be relevant, but I'm not really sure what it means:

```
02-14 17:19:29.537  5612  5612 V MediaPlayer: resetDrmState:  mDrmInfo=null mDrmProvisioningThread=null mPrepareDrmInProgress=false mActiveDrmScheme=false
02-14 17:19:29.537  5612  5612 V MediaPlayer: cleanDrmObj: mDrmObj=null mDrmSessionId=null
02-14 17:19:29.538  1119  2261 D NuPlayerDriver: reset(0xeab4a500) at state 4
02-14 17:19:29.539  1223  4542 I AS.AudioService: releasePlayer: 39 currentPackageName:com.android.chrome
02-14 17:19:29.539  1119  7508 W AMessage: failed to post message as target looper for handler 0 is gone.
02-14 17:19:29.539  1223  4542 I OpAudioMonitor: MDM,stop.
02-14 17:19:29.540  1119  7508 D NuPlayerDriver: notifyResetComplete(0xeab4a500)
```

and

```
02-14 17:19:32.091  3918  3918 D TouchInteractionService: onInputEvent# ev: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=614.0, y[0]=715.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, classification=NONE, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=109664, downTime=109664, deviceId=6, source=0x1002, displayId=0 }
02-14 17:19:32.096  3918  3918 I Surface : opservice is null false
02-14 17:19:32.096  3894  3894 I Surface : opservice is null false
02-14 17:19:32.097   921  1000 I SurfaceFlinger: surface flinger receiver command 20001 .....
02-14 17:19:32.098   921  1000 I SurfaceFlinger: surface flinger receiver command 20001 .....
02-14 17:19:32.123   816  2840 I vendor.qti.bluetooth@1.0-ibs_handler: ProcessIbsCmd: Received IBS_SLEEP_IND: 0xFE
02-14 17:19:32.159  4019  4019 D MediaBrowserCompat: Connecting to a MediaBrowserService.
02-14 17:19:32.162   566   566 E SELinux : avc:  denied  { find } for interface=vendor.qti.hardware.servicetracker::IServicetracker sid=u:r:system_server:s0 pid=1223 scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:default_android_hwservice:s0 tclass=hwservice_manager permissive=0
02-14 17:19:32.184  1223  4920 I MediaFocusControl: abandonAudioFocus() from uid/pid 10118/4019 clientId=android.media.AudioManager@7c6e8dcau.com.shiftyjelly.pocketcasts.core.player.d@cc5de5
02-14 17:19:32.197   566   566 E SELinux : avc:  denied  { find } for interface=vendor.qti.hardware.servicetracker::IServicetracker sid=u:r:system_server:s0 pid=1223 scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:default_android_hwservice:s0 tclass=hwservice_manager permissive=0
02-14 17:19:32.205  4019 14234 D AudioTrack: ClientUid 10118 AudioTrack::pause 
02-14 17:19:32.207  1223  4920 I AS.AudioService: playerEvent: 63 event: 3 isMusicActive:true device:2 currentPackageName:au.com.shiftyjelly.pocketcasts
02-14 17:19:32.207  1223  4920 I OpAudioMonitor: MDM,stop.
02-14 17:19:32.207  1223  4920 I OpAudioMonitor: MDM,stop startTime:1581729563 endTime:1581729572
02-14 17:19:32.208  1223  4920 I OpAudioMonitor: MDM, playing,device:5 lapse:9
02-14 17:19:32.208  1223  4920 I OpAudioMonitor: MDM,device:2 lapse:9 packageName:au.com.shiftyjelly.pocketcasts
02-14 17:19:32.208  1223  4920 I OpAudioMonitor: MDM,stop remove start time for:au.com.shiftyjelly.pocketcasts
02-14 17:19:32.208  1223  1786 I OpAudioMonitor: logMdm run preserveOsData tag:audio_connect
```

If anyone wants to look at the full log it's here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1S30aOzaIg3CqdDKqSr88N-QDIADm2HeV

If anyone has any ideas as to what would be causing this I'd love to hear! 
Thanks!

Comment: Are these apps in the foreground when they stutter? Or let's say you are driving with Goggle Maps or Waze and these streaming apps are in the background? What kind of phone?

Comment: It stopped happening at some point, not sure what changed.

When it happened to Youtube Vanced it was in the foreground. With Pocketcasts it may have been in the background. Phone is a OnePlus 6T.

Comment: I'm with a OnePlus 6, and I was asking because background process and service killing is a not fully specified and the heuristic is up to the manufacturer. OnePlus is very aggressive in this sense: https://dontkillmyapp.com/ But if it's in the foreground then killing should not happen. How many apps do you usually have running at the same time. I try to keep at 4-5 at max.

Comment: I don't think it was so much killing the app as it was just pausing the media. Like I'd be watching a video and then it would pause. It would still be up on the screen, and I'd just hit the play button to resume it.

Comment: it can be indirect: maybe some related service gets whacked, then you see unexpected null, reset, abandon, denied and similar in LogCat. It'll be hard to tell.